# How to replace a row from a table with another row from another table?

Tags: sql, windows, oracle

I have the following code on SQL:

```
select u.openid, u.screenname, svd.user_name
from gw_svd_prefix_assignment svd
join user_ u
on u.screenname = svd.USER_NAME;
```

now it will show three rows, screenname, user_name and openID. The screenname and user_name are the exact same, that's why I joined them, but I want to change the user_name to the value of openID which is different.

How can I do so?

**EDIT** Below is an example:

```
OPENID        SCREENNAME         USER_NAME
==========================================
Smith.A       Smith.Alan         Smith.Alan
Someone.J     Someone.Juan       Someone.Juan
Foo.V         Foo.Vallery        Foo.Vallery
Hee.L         Hee.Lee            Hee.Lee
```

I want the table to look like:

```
OPENID        SCREENNAME         USER_NAME
==========================================
Smith.A       Smith.Alan         Smith.A
Someone.J     Someone.Juan       Someone.J
Foo.V         Foo.Vallery        Foo.V
Hee.L         Hee.Lee            Hee.L
```

so I want to replace the values in User_Name with the corresponding ones from OPENID

Comment: show us sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you give example

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Can you please add more details

Comment: Did you mean "replace a **column** in one table with a **column** from another table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `screenname` is not unique in the `user_` table, then the requirement doesn't make sense (which row in the `user_` table should be used to update a row in `svd`, if the `screenname` is not unique?)

If `screenname` **is** unique, then the update can be done very easily as shown below, but this requires a UNIQUE constraint on `screenname` (or a Primary Key constraint). If a constraint doesn't exist currently, it can be added with an `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...` statement.

```
update ( select user_name, openid, screenname 
           from svd join usr on svd.user_name = usr.screenname )
set user_name = openid;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Try this

`select u.openid, u.screenname, u.openid user_name
from gw_svd_prefix_assignment svd
join user_ u
on u.screenname = svd.USER_NAME;`

Comment: The question is about an UPDATE, how does this answer that question in any way?